# Can one get vw or vh fixed value at page load?

Tags: css

I would like to have a vertically and horizontally centered `div` that is `70vw` wide and `70vh` high.  Something like this:

```
.centeredBox {
  width: 70vw;
  height: 70vh;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}
```

However, I don't want the width and height to be recalculated every time that the viewport's size changes. If possible I would like the `70vw` and `70vh` to only be calculated at page load, so it starts at that size, but also stays that size regardless of if the browser window is resized.  Is it possible to convert `vw` or `vh` values to a pixel count?

Please, no Javascript. I need this "NoScript compliant".

Comment: No, it will not possible

Comment: CSS can't do that. Its relative units works against what is, not what was.

Comment: If don't want the width and height to be recalculated every time that the viewport's size changes, then why use VW or VH, just use PX. try this link for calculation. hope it might help. https://codepen.io/lakshmiR/pen/YGWXoo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not possible with CSS. I would suggest to play around with pixels and see what comes close to what you're thinking. 
Speaking for myself, I wouldn't choose pixels though. The beauty of relative units is that they allow you to build something suitable for different devices. Why wouldn't you want your design to be responsive?

Comment: I just wanted the original `70vw` and `70vh` to be the `div`'s max-size so it would resize if it was too small to fit on the screen. Oh well. I just went with a fixed `800x600` size for my `div`. if it gets smaller than that it just fills the screen completely.