# fixed vw units while positioning block to the right side

Tags: javascript, css, css-position

I have to use relative position (not absolute to keep element in the flow) and find a way to show element at the right edge of screen.
But on some devices text not always sticks to right side.
On mobile devices it's ok, but when width size about to 2000px the text gets cut off, sometimes the white  gap gets bigger. I found a similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54878927/can-one-get-vw-or-vh-fixed-value-at-page-load) but there was no js, which is not my case.
Is it possible to do that using vw for left and vh for top?

```css
html, body {margin: 0; padding: 0}

#te {
    background-color: red;
    position: relative;
    left: 98.8vw;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<body>
    <span id="te">text</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `body { text-align: end; }`, or `body { direction: rtl; }`?

Comment: Just as the previous comment suggested; I also got confused a bit what your exact problem? Like do you want a specific styling for screen sizes above **2000px**? Are you allowed to set @media CSS rules? Something like `@media (min-width: 2000px) {//...styles here};`

Comment: I want to align this span text to the right using units vw, previous suggestion didn't worked for me

Comment: @le4a The span element is [inline-element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/span) so you must wrap it around block-level element like `div` with attribute `id="parent"`; and in your CSS style its position, like the example above: `#parent { text-align: end; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

combine it with translate:

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0
}

#te {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block; /* you need this for transform */
  position: relative;
  left: 100vw;
  transform: translate(-100%);
}
```

```html
<span id="te">text</span>
```